# I would like to know how to link 2 or more Combobox values

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, combobox

I would like to know how to link 2 or more Combobox values,
Example;

I have **jcombobox1** with values **room1** and **room2** with items **bed1**, **bed2** and **bed3** 
The question is, lets say I run my program and select **room1** and **bed2** then click save, this two values will be added to my database, and when i go back to select **room1** again, **bed2** should be cleared from **jcombobox2** and so will the same apply to **bed1** and **bed3** when i do the same save action.

when I come to select **room2**, it should have **bed1**,**bed2** and **bed3** readily available to be selected.

I would appreciate a method to link **jcombobox1** items with **jcombobox2** items separately, without one affecting values of the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a new object, that will be very useful in this case, here is an example :

```
Public class Combo_Set()
{
     String room=new String();
     Lis<String> bed== new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

Then you create a List of Combo_Set so you can fill your combobox from it.